# HTML - unable to place a div at the bottom of another div

Tags: html, css

I was just wondering if something like this would be possible:

```
<div id="inventory" >
    Blabla <BR/>
    Blabla 
    <div id="empty_slots">
        <div class="shop_empty_slot"></div>
        <div class="shop_empty_slot"></div>
        <div class="shop_empty_slot"></div>
        <div class="shop_empty_slot"></div>
        <div class="shop_empty_slot"></div>
        <div class="shop_empty_slot"></div>
        <div style="clear: both"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[JFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wracker/YLcHB/)**

I'd like to have the `#empty_slots` div to be placed at the bottom of `#inventory` (without changing the position to absolute).

So far it only works when I set the position to absolute. But this is then causing issues
when I place more elements to the div. They're all being placed behind the `#empty_slots` instead of just expanding the `#inventory` height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got it almost right, you should place the parent (`#inventory`) relative, which you already have. And place the child (`#empty-slots`) absolute instead of relative.

You said you didn't want to place it absolute, but without it, you can't achieve what you want. Is there are reason why you don't want it absolute?

Check the [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLcHB/1/).

Comment: well when I place more text on top of the #empty_slots it all goes befind the div. Not sure if I need to I place the text into another div or span perhaps?

Comment: Add a `padding-bottom` to `#inventory` in at least the same height as `#empty-slots`. See [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLcHB/15/). Note that this will only work if `#empty-slots` have a fixed height.

Comment: Your welcome, if the answer suits you, please mark it as solution (v mark on the left of the answer).